# When I ssh into my django ElasticBeanstalk server and try to enter the shell I get the error: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a ElasticBeanstalk server that is running my Django Rest Framework. The server is working properly when I make requests with Postman. However when I ssh into the server and try to enter the shell with `./manage shell_plus` I receive the error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

On the server `/opt/python/current/env` contains `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="myproject.settings.production"`

`myproject/settings/production.py` contains `from myproject.settings.base import *` which contains the secret_key settings. And like I said my endpoints are working properly.

I can't figure out why I am only having this issue with the server when I ssh and try to do any `./manage` commands.

Comment: Have you activated the python env that runs your project after sshing into the instance?

Comment: yes I activate it with `source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate`

Comment: Which EB platform do you use? Is it based on Amazon Linux 1 or 2?

Comment: `Python 3.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux`. Does that answer your question? -edit yeah looks like that means Amazon Linux 1

Comment: Yes, it does answer. I asked because on AL2 the paths are different. Not sure about AL1.